# Partition function of classical quadrupole in an electric field

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electric-fields

The partition function of a dipole in an electric field is a well-known problem, analytical solvable (nice integral, can be calculated with pen and paper), for example in the Langevin treatment of paramagnetism.

I'm right now looking at a classical quadrupole in an electric field. This looks very different, and I have not been able to solve it by myself. Before I try harder and reinvent the (broken) wheel, would anyone know if it's been addressed, and possibly solved, before?

---

**The way I see it:** I consider a quadrupole $\mathcal{Q}$ fixed in space but with free orientation. It interacts with an electric field $\mathbf{E}$, whose derivatives form the tensor $\mathcal{E}$ ($\mathcal{E}_{ij} = \frac{\partial E_i}{\partial x_j}$). The potential energy is thus:

$$ U = \frac{1}{3} \mathcal{E}:\mathcal{Q}  $$

and the partition function I want to calculate is:

$$ Z = \int \exp\left(-U/kT\right) $$

where the integral is taken over all orientations of the quadrupole with respect to the field, i.e. a 3D rotation matrix determined by three angle $(\theta,\phi,\xi)$. I've started doing this integral, but neither my brain nor Mathematica can express it in a nice way.

*I don't know if I'm missing a way to solve this in this fashion, or if it would be better attacked from another angle…*

Comment: It would help quite a bit of you posted how you're paying the problem, particularly to know what internal degrees of freedom you're giving your quadrupole.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I've added (after the break) a description of how I approached the problem